# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to train my Deep Neural Network to recognizing handwritten numbers but I keep getting the error stated previously in the title and I don't know why.

I tried reshaping "x_train" and "y_train", didn't change the result.
model.add(Flatten()) did not work aswell.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

train_images = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
test_images = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')
train_images /= 255
test_images /= 255

train_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
test_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu", input_shape=(784,)))

for x in range (0, 10):
    model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))

model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=2, validation_split=0.0, shuffle=True, initial_epoch=0, validation_data=(train_images, train_labels), steps_per_epoch=10, validation_steps=10, validation_freq=1)
```

I'm expecting the training to start but I get this errror instead: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing training dataset without reshaping it.

Instead of this line:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=2, validation_split=0.0, shuffle=True, initial_epoch=0, validation_data=(train_images, train_labels), steps_per_epoch=10, validation_steps=10, validation_freq=1)
```

Use this:

```
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=100, verbose=2, validation_split=0.0, shuffle=True, initial_epoch=0, validation_data=(train_images, train_labels), steps_per_epoch=10, validation_steps=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the dataset from having shape (n, width, height) to (n, depth, width, height).

`X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)`